# How to check whether a person is logged-in atleast once in a day and how to calculate the length of session of login in mysql-flask application?

Tags: database-schema, mysql-python, flask-login, web-development-server

I am using mysql and flask to develop a time-cards management system (which is basically an attendance taking software), in which I need to check the time a user is logged in and logged out and the interval of the session to calculate his working time and I should be able to update the database as a leave if he didn't login the whole day. And I need to store the data monthly-wise so that we can calculate the salary of the employee depending on his working hours and leaves in that month.

**Can someone please help me how to**:

1. Design my database such that we can store the monthly information of all 
   employees efficiently (like should i create a table for each month or some 
   other way?)
2. How to check the time of login and logout and the length of session of a 
   user?
3. How to check whether a user is logged in at least once in a day or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record the start and end time of each work period in a table.

```
create table time_record (
    time_record_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    start_time datetime not null,
    end_time datetime not null,
    person_id int not null references person(person_id)
);
```

Then you can report on daily or monthly activity for each user with some simple queries. For instance, to roll up to a daily summary, you can join a set of calendar days against the time records.

Comment: Using this schema, how can i find if a person is logged in at least once on a day? Because i need to know this as i need to update the database of the person either with the number of working hours or should increment number of his leaves. Thanks!!

Comment: Join the calendar days in the period you're reporting on with the employees and time entries. Each employee and day will have 0 or more hours.